# TypeScript Enum variable logging

Tags: typescript

I have a enum variable in typescript which is look like this

```
export enum VoucherType {
    DebitVoucher = 1,
    CreditVoucher = 2,
    PurchaseVoucher = 19
}
```

After logging

```
console.log(VoucherType);
```

**the output is something wrong**

```
{
1: "DebitVoucher", 
2: "CreditVoucher", 
19: "PurchaseVoucher", 
DebitVoucher: 1, 
CreditVoucher: 2, 
PurchaseVoucher: 19}1: 
"DebitVoucher"2: 
"CreditVoucher"19: 
"PurchaseVoucher"CreditVoucher: 2DebitVoucher: 1PurchaseVoucher: 19: Object
```

I need the actual JavaScript object, how could I get this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is how typescript enum works, enum does mirror so you can get key by value, if you don't need it just use plain object instead.

Comment: The output is a bit different than stated in your question:
`{ '1': 'DebitVoucher',
  '2': 'CreditVoucher',
  '19': 'PurchaseVoucher',
  DebitVoucher: 1,
  CreditVoucher: 2,
  PurchaseVoucher: 19 }`

Comment: @Bouke, yes, how could i get the solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define enum property value as string. Then it should work.

```
export enum VoucherType {
    DebitVoucher = '1',
    CreditVoucher = '2',
    PurchaseVoucher = '19'
}

console.log(VoucherType);  // output {"DebitVoucher":"1","CreditVoucher":"2","PurchaseVoucher":"19"}
```

Comment: 1, 2, 19 is my number not string

Comment: Yes, agree its default typescript handling for enum properties. You can get the key using Object.keys() and apply parseInt().